# Map box JS not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mapbox-gl-js

Hi I am developing NodeJS project with using pug.
Not able to load the api https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.0/mapbox-gl.js file from pug template.

In chrome getting the error in console.
Please find the below image for reference
[image]

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated to answer without having the code. But it seems that it can't load because of a security problem. And kaspersky gets involved.

Maybe try to edit the metq

"**mapboxlg**" is not defined

Maybe it's because the CDN only allows HTTPS requests and given your localhost development link it's only HTTP and for the CDN it's not secure.

This is just speculation because again, you didn't put any code

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I will check with CDN

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the hosts for csp whitelist in res headers of your pages.

Refer to this for detailed information:
[CSP directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/base-uri)

After stumbling over the same problem and researching for a day, this worked for me:
Before you render you page, set the header like below:

```
res.set({
'Content-Security-Policy': `default-src 'self' http: https:;block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data: blob:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self' https://api.mapbox.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';script-src-elem https: http: ;script-src-attr 'self' https://api.mapbox.com https://cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline';style-src 'self' https://api.mapbox.com https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';worker-src 'self' blob:`
});
```

Now either you can keep doing this before rendering every page, or place this code in a middleware in you main app, just before you've defined your router for rendering the html pages.

Something like this:

```
<appName>.use( (req, res, next)=>{ 
res.set....//as done above
next(); 
});
```

In future, if something stops working, inspect browser window and look in console, you'll just need to whitelist some other trusted sources.

Comment: Its working fine Thank you so much @Vinay